# occassional javac name clash errors in Jenkins build

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, ant, enums

I occasionally get name clash errors in a java project built with Jenkins.

I've seen it in a couple places, and it both places it follows the following format:

```
public class Foo {
    public enum FooEnum {
        VALUE1("Val1"),
        VALUE2("Val2)

        private FooEnum(String) { /*code*/}
    }
}
```

And the error output would say:

```
 [javac] /path/Foo.java:6: error: name clash: FooEnum(String) and FooEnum(String) have the same erasure
[javac]   private FooEnum(String)
                  ^
```

Note that there is only one method named FooEnum, so its not a case of type erasure issues or anything like that. The method seems to be somehow conflicting with itself.

I develop the code in Eclipse and my codebase spans multiple Eclipse projects in the same workspace. For my Jenkin's pipeline, I have a job for each Eclipse project.

When each project finishes, it archives the whole project directory (which includes the source and the .class files). Downstream projects then copy the archived objects from the previous builds so that they can use them as dependencies.

I am using ant build.xml files which are auto-generated from eclipse.

These errors don't show up super often, but when they do, they usually persist for a few builds and then go away. I have not been able to figure out any pattern indicating when they occur and when they don't.

I have never had any issues when building within Eclipse, so I think the issue must have more to do with my Jenkins setup or the build files.

Unfortunately, do to my companies strict proprietary information protection policies, I'm a little apprehensive about sharing any actual code or actual ant files here, but I was hoping someone would have an idea they could share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by explicitly copying in the dependency projects required for each job and making sure that I only copied in those projects.

Previously, I would sometimes copy in all of the artifacts from a few jobs that had the dependencies I needed. I think that something weird was happening in the cases where a dependency was found in multiple jobs that I copied in. I still haven't figured out exactly what's going on, but this seems to have fixed it.